# Proof of non-solvability of general equations of one unknown in elementary terms (finite terms)?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, closed-form-expressions, alternative-proof

This question relates to the solvability of equations of one unknown in elementary terms (finite terms) according to Liouville and Ritt.

Elementary equations and closed-form solutions can be important in mathematics and in the natural sciences, e.g. for discovering and describing certain relationships.

My conjecture below is an extension of the theorems of [Lin 1983] and [Chow 1999]. See the definitions therein.

$\mathbb{L}$ are the [Liouvillian numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillianNumber.html). They are generated by applying (explicit and implicit) algebraic and/or  (explicit and implicit) elementary functions to $\mathbb{Q}$.
$\mathbb{E}$ are the [Elementary numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElementaryNumber.html) defined in [Chow 1999]. They are generated by applying explicit algebraic and/or explicit elementary functions to $\mathbb{Q}$.

1.)
Could you please give better formulations for the conjecture?

2.)
Could you please give here a well formulated correct complete comprehensive proof of the conjecture?
Because the conjecture is new, the answer here would be a scientific publication.
The very simple and short proof method from [Chow 1999] could be used.

3.)
Is the extension to
$P\left(E_{a_1}(z_0),...,E_{a_m}(z_0),\ln(E_{b_1}(z_0)),...,\ln(E_{b_n}(z_0)),e^{E_{a_1}(z_0)},...,e^{E_{a_m}(z_0)},E_{b_1}(z_0),...,E_{b_n}(z_0))\right)=0$ possible?

4.)
Can the components in the argument of $P$ that don't contain $e$ or $\ln$ be summarized to $z_0$ if the $E_i$ or $E_{i_j}$ are algebraic functions over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$?

**Conjecture:**
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}_+$. Let $P$ be a nonzero irreducible polynomial in $2n$ indeterminates that is algebraic over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. Let $E_1,...,E_n$ be elementary functions, $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$, $E_1(z_0),...,E_n(z_0)\neq 0$, and $\{E_1(z_0),...,E_n(z_0)\}$ algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.
If Schanuel's conjecture is true and $P\left(E_1(z_0),...,E_n(z_0),e^{E_1(z_0)},...,e^{E_n(z_0)}\right)=0$, then
a) $z_0\notin\mathbb{L}$,
b) $z_0\notin\mathbb{E}$.

$\ $

[[Chow 1999] Chow, T.: What is a closed-form number. Am. Math. Monthly 106 (1999) (5) 440-448](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf)

[[Lin 1983] Ferng-Ching Lin: Schanuel's Conjecture Implies Ritt's Conjectures. Chin. J. Math. 11 (1983) (1) 41-50](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43836165)

$\ $

**Proof Idea**:

The equation from the conjecture (main equation) is a zeroing equation of $P$. If $z_0$ is a solution of this equation, the set $\{E_1(z_0),...,E_n(z_0),e^{E_1(z_0)},...,e^{E_n(z_0)}\}$ is algebraically dependent over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ because $P$ is an algebraic function over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. We want to show that the set $\{E_1(z_0),...,E_n(z_0),e^{E_1(z_0)},...,e^{E_n(z_0)}\}$ is algebraic independent over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ for each $z_0\in dom(E_1)\cap\ ...\ \cap dom(E_n)$. We do this with Schanuel's conjecture. We use i.a. the proof method from [Chow 1999].

Schanuel's conjecture reads as follows:

**Conjecture** Schanuel's conjecture [Lang 1966]
Let $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ be complex numbers, linearly independent over the rationals. Then the transcendence degree of the field $\mathbb{Q}\left(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n,e^{\alpha_1},...,e^{\alpha_n}\right)$ is at least $n$.

**Corollary**
Let $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ be complex numbers, linearly independent over the rationals. Then the transcendence degree of the field $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\left(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n,e^{\alpha_1},...,e^{\alpha_n}\right)$ is at least $n$.

Start with proving the part of the conjecture for the Liouvillian numbers.

Start with $E_1,...,E_n=id$.

We need some preliminaries.

Extend Chow's definition of a tower for $z_0\in\mathbb{L}$.

If $S=(\alpha_{1_1},...,\alpha_{n_1},\alpha_{1_2},...,\alpha_{n_2},...,\ \ \alpha_{1_m},...,\alpha_{n_m})$ is a finite sequence of complex numbers, then for brevity we write $S_i$ for the field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_{1_1},...,\alpha_{n_1},e^{\alpha_{1_1}},...,e^{\alpha_{n_1}},\alpha_{1_2},...,\alpha_{n_2},e^{\alpha_{1_2}},...,e^{\alpha_{n_2}},...,\ \ \alpha_{1_i},...,\alpha_{n_i},e^{\alpha_{1_i}},...,e^{\alpha_{n_i}})$.
In particular, $S_0=\mathbb{Q}$.

**Definition**
A tower is a finite sequence $S=(\alpha_{1_1},...,\alpha_{n_1},\alpha_{1_2},...,\alpha_{n_2},...,\ \ \alpha_{1_m},...,\alpha_{n_m})$ of nonzero complex numbers such that for all $i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$ and $j\in\{1,2,...,m\}$, there exists a function $F_{i_j}\colon D_{F_{i_j}}\subseteq\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C},z\mapsto F_{i_j}(z)$, algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, such that $F_{i_j}(\alpha_{i_j})\in S_{i-1}$ or $e^{\alpha_{i_j}}\in S_{i-1}$ (or both).
A tower is reduced, or a reduced tower, if the set $\{\alpha_{1_1},...,\alpha_{n_1},\alpha_{1_2},...,\alpha_{n_2},...,\ \ \alpha_{1_m},...,\alpha_{n_m}\}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.
If $(\beta_1,\beta_2,...,\beta_n)\in\mathbb{C}^n$, then a tower for $(\beta_1,\beta_2,...,\beta_n)$ is a tower $S=(\beta_{1_1},...,\beta_{n_1},\beta_{1_2},...,\beta_{n_2},...,\beta_{1_m},...,\beta_{n_m})$ such that $\beta\in S_m$.

Show that for any $\gamma\in\mathbb{L}$, there exists a tower for $\gamma$.
Extend Chow's reduction lemma.
Extend Chow's division lemma.
Reduce the tower for algebraically dependent components.
Show that the main equation is algebraic over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ for 
$\alpha_{n_1},\alpha_{n_2},...,\alpha_{n_m},\ e^{\alpha_{n_1}},e^{\alpha_{n_2}},...,e^{\alpha_{n_m}}$.
Show with Schanuel's conjecture hat this set is algebraically independent over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

This would prove that $z_0\notin\mathbb{L}$ if $E_1,...,E_n=id$.

Let $E_i$ be an elementary function. If $z_0\in\mathbb{L}$, then $E_i(z_0)\in\mathbb{L}$. If $z_0\notin\mathbb{L}$, then $E_i(z_0)\notin\mathbb{L}$.

This would prove the part of the conjecture with the Liouvillian numbers.

Prove the part of the conjecture with the Elementary numbers:
$\mathbb{E}\subseteq\mathbb{L}\ \curvearrowright\ z_0\notin\mathbb{L}\implies z_0\notin\mathbb{E}$

This would prove the part of the conjecture with the Elementary numbers.

This would prove the whole conjecture.

$\ $

to be continued

A proof only for the part of the conjecture for the elementary numbers would also be possible.